# Does Java PriorityQueue rearrange itself when I change the key of an entry?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Suppose I have a priority queue

```
class Node{
        public int id;
        public int dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        public Node(int id) { this.id = id; }
}

Queue<Node> q = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.dist, b.dist));
```

Then if I did (suppose one/two are nodes objects)

```
Node one = new Node(1);
Node two = new Node(2);
one.dist = 1;
two.dist = 2;
q.offer(one);
q.offer(two);
two.dist = -1;
```

What will be the behavior of the queue? Will `two` appear before now?

Thanks!

Comment: @BeeOnRope, I have no clue how it can be more complete...

Comment: Why not just run the code and find out?

Comment: No, it will not. The queue has no idea about the properties of the items in it or of they change. You would need to remove, update, insert.

Comment: Your code causes undefined behaviour. The documentation specifically states that you can't do this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Unless you can come up with a specification of what should happen, yes it is.

Comment: What you want to do would be the same as using your `Node` as a key in a `Map`.  The `Map` implementation is not aware of external modifications to the fields of `Node` that determine its hash code, so modifying any of those fields leads to UB.

Comment: @EJP I was expecting to find a prohibition against this in the Javadoc for PriorityQueue but couldn't find it. Could you reference where you found it?

Answer (score 1):

Different implementations of the Java API might behave differently. But, with respect to OpenJDK: no. Operations such as `peek` do not re-sort the collection: they merely return the first value in an already sorted collection. So unless you use a method of the queue it has no way of knowing the order has changed.

In fact even calling `add` (for example) won't resort existing items: it assumes the existing items are sorted as it shuffles the new item to the right place in the queue.

See [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/PriorityQueue.java) from the openJDK implementation.